# How to make back button work with angular state

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs here.
The home page is composed by tabs. So at the top of the page I have this:

```
    <div
         ng-repeat="itemName in home.menuItems() track by $index">
         <a href="" ng-click="homeView.goToLink($index)">
            {{itemName}}
         </a>
    </div>
```

In route.js I have this:

```
function routeConfiger($stateProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('home.mypage', {
        url: '/mypage/:tabId',
        templateUrl: 'home-view.html',
        controller: 'homeViewCtrl',
        params: { tabId: 0}
    })
}
});
```

Finally, in controller I have this:

```
goToLink = (tabId) => {
     $state.go("home.mypage", {
        tabId: tabId
     });
  }
```

Well, this works. I click on tabs, and the content of the clicked one is showed. But when I click on back button, I still see the content of the last clicked tab. At the same time, the url changes.
So basically:

```
1 - I go to mypage.com. The url shows: mypage.com
2 - I click on the second tab. The url shows: mypage.com/1
3 - I click on the thirth tab. The url shows: mypage.com/2
4 - I go back with browser's back button. The url shows: mypage.com/1
5 - I go back with browser's back button. The url shows: mypage.com
```

However, when Im at step 4 and 5 I still see the content of the second tab.

At the top of the controller, I always print this:

```
console.log($stateParams.tabId );
```

As long as I go to a tab by clicking on the menu element, then the tabId corresponds to the showed onw. But when going back, it will always print the latest clicked tab.

Comment: But when going back, it will always print the latest clicked tab. -- your url chages and $stateParams not? are you sure?

Comment: Yes I am sure, believe me.